# Catching value of text box using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have a button and text box displayed. Have the user enter a number. That a random number will be generated and the user has 10 attempts to answer the question correctly. The script should check whether the users number is either equal to, less than, or greater than the random number. I am having trouble getting the number inputted from the text-box.

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm">
        <div id='myForm'></div>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
   function partC(){
            var guessCount = 10;
            var random = Math.round(Math.random()*100);

            var button = document.createElement('input');
            button.type = "button";
            button.value = " Guess! ";
            document.getElementById('myForm').appendChild(button);
            var textbox = document.createElement('input');
            textbox.type = 'number';
            document.getElementById('myForm').appendChild(textbox);
            var check = document.getElementById('textbox').value
            button.onclick = calc(guessCount, random, check);

    }

    function calc(guessCount, random, check){
        while(guessCount > 0) {
                if (check == random){
                    alert("Correct!");
                } else if (check > random) {
                    alert("Try Again. Guess to High. " + guessCount + " tries left.");
                } else if (check < random) {
                    alert("Try Again. Guess to Low. " + guessCount + " tries left.");
                }
            guessCount--;

        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is assigning callback function result to onclick event instead of function itself. Besides, you are also trying to run a while loop which will consume guessCount on first click event.

I edited code, following should work:

```
   function partC(){
            var guessCount = 10;
            var random = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
            var button = document.createElement('input');
            button.type = "button";
            button.value = " Guess! ";
            document.getElementById('myForm').appendChild(button);
            var textbox = document.createElement('input');
            textbox.type = 'number';
            document.getElementById('myForm').appendChild(textbox);
            button.onclick = function(){
            var check = textbox.value*1;
            if (check == random){
                    alert("Correct!");
                } else if (check > random) {
                    alert("Try Again. Guess to High. " + guessCount + " tries left.");
                } else if (check < random) {
                    alert("Try Again. Guess to Low. " + guessCount + " tries left.");
                }
            guessCount--;

            }

    }
```

Comment: Bingo you got it. Thank you, that was my second issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the value by using id, whereas you didn't give any id to your input.

Try this:

```
textbox.id = 'textbox';
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the set the id of your textbox element. Try adding the id after creating it. Then you can get the element by its id, which in your case is `textbox`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myEl = document.getElementById('a');

myEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(document.getElementById('text').value);
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text"/>
<button id="a">Alert text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has a wonderful option available for you,

```
$('#unique-id').val();
```

The unique ID will be whatever value that specific textarea. So in this case:

```
<textarea id="unique-id"></textarea>
```

Comment: The OP did not mention that they are using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add this to what all the other answers say. You probably want a semicolon after this line:

```
 var check = document.getElementById('textbox').value
```